# Using Python scripts with PIP packages in Unity3D game scripts

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, import, pip

I have bunch of functionality written in Python that I would like to use in Unity3D (Possibly 2018 or 2019). I considered using UniPython or IronPython but from what I read these plugins only embed Python ,as in you can use the syntax but not python packages installed with pip, which my code uses.

Can anyone confirm if the available python plugins will actually allow this or if not - Is there a way I can add my python code into Unity without having to rewrite them in C# and have to look for equivalent C# libraries?

My end goal is to be able to use my python functionality inside of Unity scripts, whether that would be C# scripts using Python functions (if at all possible) or moving to Python as a scripting language in a way that would allow me to use external python packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 2.7.5 IronPython supports pip. Maybe this will help you.

https://ironpython.net/blog/2014/12/07/pip-in-ironpython-275.html

Comment: Thanks! I ran some tests on Windows and I got it working. Now I have to figure out the setup in Linux